# VBA: Collecting and showing error messages in UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have written some code in VBA that gets data from other workbooks and then updates several "masterfiles", through which my code loops. Right now I make a backup before updating the data and at the end of the loop I save the updated file. The code works and I'm not sure how pertinent it even is to the question:

```
Sub YearlyReport()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim VWArray As Variant
Dim wbVWAggr As Workbook
Dim VWNumber As Variant

FilePath = "C:\VBA\YearlyReport\"
VWArray = Array(21, 25, 35, 45, 46, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 101)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each VWNumber In VWArray
        Set wbVWAggr = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath & "Report" & VWNumber & ".xlsx")
        wbVWAggr.SaveAs FilePath & "Report" & VWNumber & "_old" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm-ss") & ".xlsx"

        'Data gets copy pasted from other workbooks

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Overwrite old file
        wbVWAggr.SaveAs FilePath & "Report" & VWNumber & ".xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next VWNumber

Application.ScreenUpdating = True   
End Sub
```

This approach is fine, but what if a file can't be found? What I really wanna do is to continue the code, collect the error messages and show them to the user at the end (I put the code in a separate sub). I'd still have to write it, but I could then ask the user if he wants to save or cancel the whole thing:

```
Sub ErrorCollection()
    Dim ErrorCount As Long
    Dim ErrorArray() As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim VWNumber As Variant
    Dim VWArray As Variant
    Dim ErrorMessage As String
    Dim Item As Variant

    FilePath = "C:\VBA\YearlyReport\"
    VWArray = Array(21, 25, 35, 45, 46, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 101)

    For Each VWNumber In VWArray
        If Dir$(FilePath & "Report" & VWNumber & ".xlsx") = "" Then
            ErrorMessage = "Report" & VWNumber & " cannot be found."
            ReDim Preserve ErrorArray(ErrorCount)
            ErrorArray(ErrorCount) = ErrorMessage
            ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
        End If
    Next VWNumber

    If ErrorCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox Join(ErrorArray, vbCrLf)
    End If
End Sub
```

Ideally the user can also hide the popup message to look at the files, which means using a UserForm - but in that case how do I show the error messages like in the MsgBox? I tried googling, but I only came across questions how to populate an array from a userform.

Comment: How about a new UF with a Label that gets populated with `Join(ErrorArray, vbCrLf)`? Make sure you make ErrorArray a public variable in order for the new UF to read it.

Comment: @TimStack: not sure if you need to make `ErrorArray` a public variable. If a label is update, you could just update the label directly from UDF (as long as the form is exposed). NoNameNo123: you could have a checkbox in your form which user can select to show or hide error message. Than you can check the checkbox status and `ErrorCount` to decide if the error should be shown

Comment: @Zac that's true. Public variable if it is populated from it's own module, private if populated from within the original UF.